# Pandas: how to change format like "year-month" to datetime64 format?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I want to change the column `yearmonth` which dtype is `object` into column `date` which dtype is `datetime64[ns]`.

`Input:`

```
yearmonth
0   2017-07
1   2019-10
```

`Expected:`

```
yearmonth   data
0   2017-07 2017-07-01
1   2019-10 2019-10-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['yearmonth'], format='%Y-%m')
```